# Proper mime-type for patch files

Tags: svn, mime-types, patch

Anybody know what the "proper" mime-type for patch files would be?  I have been using application/octet-stream because I don't see anything better at [iana.org](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html).  Is application/octet-stream correct, or is there something else that fits better?  Why is there no `application/patch` type?

Obviously, one possible answer is `text/plain`, but I have seen many patch files which include data which is not purely text.  Is `text/plain` the best choice if you know for a fact all content is text, or is it better to be consistent across all patch files?

I should say the context I am mainly thinking about this in is setting mime-type as a clue to subversion about handling line-endings (`svn:mime-type` and `svn:eol-style`).  The issue is that a patch file may patch both files which use `eol-style native` as well as `non-native`, which can lead to line-ending weirdness when applying a patch post-checkout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find an authoritative version either.  Here's some other possibilities:

- `text/x-diff`
- `text/x-patch`
- `application/x-patch`

For what it's worth, [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (a ticket tracker with good svn support) uses `text/x-patch` for diffs. [git.kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org) and [GitHub](https://github.com/github/fetch/pull/592.patch) use `text/plain`.

Answer (score 1):

If your patch only contains text, I would prefer `text/plain` over `text/x-patch` or `text/x-diff`. IMO, `text/x-patch` or `-diff` is more suitable for this purpose, and is recommended by [some projects](http://ffmpeg.org/developer.html#patch-submission-checklist), but the main reason for `text/plain` is compatibility.

In Gmail if the attachment is `text/plain`, when you click it it will automatically pop up a document preview; but it will not for `text/x-patch` or `text/x-diff`. Another example is the archive interface of Mailman (a popular mailing list management software): it [shows the text](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2014-April/156157.html) with `text/plain`, but [does not](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2014-June/158279.html) with `text/x-patch`.

If your patch contains binary data, I would use `application/octet-stream`, not because it is correct but it will save you some trouble from line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you are checking in patch files to SVN. That aside, I would go with the assumption that if you have the possibility of checking binary patch files to use application/octet-stream.
I'm not sure what would happen if you mixed them... text for text, octet for binary... that might also be possible?

Comment: Patch files are commonly used in RPMs for open source products. It's a SCM-agnostic way to keep local modifications discrete from upstream source.  I check in a good number of those.

Comment: It's easy to keep patches of text files separate from patches to binary files for patches that YOU create. In fact I never create patches with binary parts. But others create them sometimes. And if you're managing them, seems like you shouldn't need to do an analysis of the actual contents of a file to discover whether you need text/plain(?) or application/octet-stream.  That's why I think application/patch makes sense.  A patch file can be a mix of text and binary with special EOL translation requirements.  Maybe patch files should include a mime-type descriptor for each of their components?